# Project Reactor async send email with retry on error

Tags: java, project-reactor

I need to send some data after user registered. I want to do first attempt in main thread, but if there are any errors, I want to retry 5 times with 10 minutes interval.

```
@Override
public void sendRegisterInfo(MailData data) {
    Mono.just(data)
        .doOnNext(this::send)
        .doOnError(ex -> logger.warn("Main queue {}", ex.getMessage()))
        .doOnSuccess(d -> logger.info("Send mail to {}", d.getRecipient()))
        .onErrorResume(ex -> retryQueue(data))
        .subscribe();
}

private Mono<MailData> retryQueue(MailData data) {
    return Mono.just(data)
               .delayElement(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
               .doOnNext(this::send)
               .doOnError(ex -> logger.warn("Retry queue {}", ex.getMessage()))
               .doOnSuccess(d -> logger.info("Send mail to {}", d.getRecipient()))
               .retry(5)
               .subscribe();
}
```

It works.
But I've got some questions:

1. Did I correct to make operation in `doOnNext` function?
2. Is it correct to use `delayElement` to make a delay between executions?
3. Did the thread blocked when waiting for delay?
4. And what the best practice to make a retries on error and make a delay between it?

Answer (score 7):

1. `doOnXXX` for logging is fine. But for the actual element processing, you must prefer using `flatMap` rather than `doOnNext` (assuming your processing is asynchronous / can be converted to returning a `Flux`/`Mono`).
2. This is correct. Another way is to turn the code around and start from a `Flux.interval`, but here `delayElement` is better IMO.
3. The delay runs on a separate thread/scheduler (by default, `Schedulers.parallel()`), so not blocking the main thread.
4. There's actually a `Retry` builder dedicated to that kind of use case in the `reactor-extra` addon: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/blob/master/reactor-extra/src/main/java/reactor/retry/Retry.java

Comment: why is not ok to do asynchronous processing on doOn** operators? I've heard this statement before but there was no clear justification on why it is not a good practice

Comment: you are essentially breaking the reactive chain, and you won't get notified of either successful completion of the process **nor error**. The main sequence could complete early, giving you the impression that everything went fine, only for the async process to fail silently in a corner a second later. This is only ever ok in a pure "fire and forget" scenario, but usually you want to at least reattach to the complete/error signals

Comment: @SimonBaslé how do i send an alert email,  an async operation, only on error?

Comment: @Ravi I'd recommend `onErrorResume(e -> sendEmail(e).then(Mono.error(e)))`. That way, if the sending of the email itself fails, the chain gets notified. Otherwise, it is (re)notified of the original error. If you're _really_ sure you don't care about that case, then by all means use `doOnError`, but usually one does care.